# Use NASM to compile 32-bit assembly for x86_64 environment

Tags: macos, assembly, x86, nasm

I'm reading a book where all the assembly code examples are written for 32-bit Linux environment, and I'm using a 64-bit Mac. I was able to compile the following program with NASM after changing `_start` to `start`. However, when I run the executable it doesn't print `hello world` as I would expect it to. Is there an option to pass to NASM to compile this in a way that will run on a 64-bit Mac?

I tried:

```
nasm -f macho32 helloworld.asm
```

and

```
nasm -f macho helloworld.asm
```

followed by:

```
ld helloworld.o -o helloworld
```

My code is:

```
section .data       ; data segment
msg     db      "Hello, world!", 0x0a   ; the string and newline char

section .text       ; text segment
global start       ; Default entry point for ELF linking

start:
  ; SYSCALL: write(1, msg, 14) 
  mov eax, 4        ; put 4 into eax, since write is syscall #4
  mov ebx, 1        ; put 1 into ebx, since stdout is 1
  mov ecx, msg      ; put the address of the string into ecx
  mov edx, 14       ; put 14 into edx, since our string is 14 bytes
  int 0x80          ; Call the kernel to make the system call happen

  ; SYSCALL: exit(0)
  mov eax, 1        ; put 1 into eax, since exit is syscall #1
  mov ebx, 0        ; exit with success
  int 0x80          ; do the syscall
```

Comment: `int 0x80` doesn't work the same on OS/X as on Linux (the system calls are different). Using Linux code as a stsarting point it ill advised. You really need an assembly language tutorial for 32-bit Mac OS/X  One reasonable starting point is here: https://filippo.io/making-system-calls-from-assembly-in-mac-os-x/

Comment: 32-bit OS/X code will run in 64-bit OS/X. If you want to create truly 64-bit OS/X code then you'll want to drop the `int 0x80` and move to using the `syscall` instruction. This differs from `int 0x80`. The calling convention is different and the system call numbers don't match with 32-bit OS/X code. You need to find a tutorial that targets 64-bit OS/X code. You also have to use `-f macho64` with NASM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simply not going to work like that. Get a VM and install 32 bit linux in the VM. The problem is not running x86_32 code on x64. The problem is trying the Linux syscall gate on MAC. There's no reason to believe that would work.